# How to Output line numbers parallel to output?

Tags: java, eclipse

Below is my code that will read lines from URL and output it. 
I was wondering how can I also output line numbers such as row numbers in excel.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class helloworld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL yahh = new URL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AqSBI1OogE84dDJyN0tyNHJENkNyYUgyczVLX0RMY3c&single=true&gid=0&range=A2%3AA200&output=txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    yahh.openStream()));

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)

            System.out.println(inputLine);

        in.close();

    }
}
```

**Currently Output is:**

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
55555
66666
77777
88888
99999
100000
```

**I want it to be**

```
1   11111
2   22222
3   33333
4   44444
5   55555
6   66666
7   77777
8   88888
9   99999
10  100000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare a `line number` variable and `increment` it inside your loop on every iteration:

```
 int line=0;
 while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
       line++;
       System.out.println(line + "\t" + inputLine); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable as row count in the output separated by tab:

```
    int rowCount = 1;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(rowCount +"\t" + inputLine);
        rowCount ++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use tab

```
int i = 1;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
  System.out.println(i++ + "\t" + inputLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain there will never be a ton of numbers, you can just use a tab, like this:

```
 int line=0;
 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
       line++;
            System.out.println(line + "\t" + inputLine); 
    }
```

If you want to make sure of protecting against very large numbers, you could do something more fancy, like:

```
 int line=0;
 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
       line++;
            System.out.println(String.format("%8s%s",line,inputLine)); 
    }
```

Where the number `8-1=7` is the most digits you ever expect to have.

Beyond that, you'd have to come up with a very sophisticated answer, essentially looping through once to detect the maximum size number, and go from there. But I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader;-)